# Why does a Container child with alignment change the stack positioning behavior in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

## The Code

```dart
    final _child1 = CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey, radius: 100.0);
    final _child2 = Container(child: Text('Mia B', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white)));
    final _child3 = Positioned(top: 35.0, left: 35.0, child: Text('Foo', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.red)));
    final _child4 = Container(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text('Bar', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.red)));

    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment(0.6, 0.6),
            children: [_child1, _child2, _child3],
          ),
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment(0.6, 0.6),
            children: [_child1, _child2, _child3, _child4],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

## The Screenshot

[image]

## Question Description

There are 2 stack children in the column.

For the first stack without `Container(alignment:)` child, the second and third children will be placed according to the first child's position.

For The second stack with `Container(alignment:)` child, I have some questions:

1. Why does the third child `Foo` place itself according to the entire width instead of the first child `CircleAvatar`? This behavior is changed from the first stack.
2. Why does the first child `CircleAvatar` change its own position? What rule applies to its current position?
3. Why does the fourth child `Container(alignment:)` change the entire layout and the width of the stack element? The width of the stack was the width of the first child, but now, it becomes the width of the parent Container.
4. Why does the fourth child's `centerRight` align with the second child 'Mia B` instead of the first child CircleAvatar? I thought the first child was the alignment base. But now the forth child has the same X axis to the second child.